# Images files still appearing in app even after deleting every supporting files Xcode 6.4

Tags: xcode, swift

I deleted all my supporting files form Xcode's project and still when I run the app some how some images are still there/appearing but when i search in the search box for the file at the bottom left of the project. It says that there no file of that name in my project does anyone know why or how this is happening? And theres nothing in assets I'm using Swift if it helps Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old things that you delete from the project are not deleted from the built app, or from the intermediates along the way. To do that, you need to *clean all the caches*, and also clean out any old built versions (e.g. *clean the simulator*, and also *delete from the device* if you've been testing on a device).

Comment: See my answer here to learn how to do a full cleaning: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6247073/341994